# What is tab injection?

Tags: php, standards

Reading on the zend framework [coding standard](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/ZF+Coding+Standards+%28RC%29#ZFCodingStandards%28RC%29-Indentation) I found this phrase:

> Editors should be configured to treat tabs as spaces 
>   in order to prevent injection of tab characters into the source
>   code.

And my question is: what *is* tab injection? I searched google but I did find this phrase in a lot of standards, so I 'm not really sure what it refers to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's nothing special, just a fancy way of saying "we don't want tabs in our source code".

As stated on the link you provide, Zend coding standards mandate that whitespace in source files must not include tabs -- all indentation must be done with spaces.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Very fitting to invoke the Lord on religious issues ;)

Answer (score 4):

"Tab injection" means the insertion of a tab as an indentation character.